# php fastcgi is crashing if the url contains &start_debug=1

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

php fastcgi is crashing if the url contains `&start_debug=1`, I am getting the following error in my nginx error log

```
2016/11/09 12:16:08 [error] 341#0: *72 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, ... request: "GET /?debug_host=127.0.0.1&start_debug=1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000",
```

How I can fix this error?

In /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/logs/php-fpm.log log I am getting the following error message

```
[09-Nov-2016 12:18:51] WARNING: [pool www] child 2243 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 394.275224 seconds from start
```

If we don't have &start_debug=1 everything is working fine I am adding &start_debug=1 for Zend debugger.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, seems like this is happening from zend debugger. I have removed the debugger then it is working fine.